# Which Kid Detective Invented a 3D Video Camera?

Tags: story-identification

I remember Encyclopedia Brown style (father with the police), except the kid was really into physics and had all these inventions.

One was called the eye-spy camera, which could video 3D through walls.

Any clue to the name of the kid and which book in the siries this is mentioned in?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but perhaps the following site might help:  "http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KidDetective".

Comment: Too, are you sure the father is a police officer?  I believe there were some Tom Swift adventures in which he used an Eye-Spy type recording camera.   I found a link at: http://elearning.zaou.ac.zm:8060/Fiction-Biographies/Appleton,%20Victor%201st/Appleton,%20Victor%20-%20Tom%20Swift%20Jr%2007%20-%20And%20His%20Diving%20Seacopter.txt

Comment: Thank you @beichst!

Here's what I was looking for: [Tom Swift and his 3D Telejector](http://www.tomswift.info/homepage/3djector.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks JNF.   Moving this to an answer.  If you concur and could mark this as correct, it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

====

I believe there were some Tom Swift adventures in which he used an Eye-Spy type recording camera. I found a link at:

[Tom Swift Bio Links](http://elearning.zaou.ac.zm:8060/Fiction-Biographies/Appleton,%20Victor%201st/Appleton,%20Victor%20-%20Tom%20Swift%20Jr%2007%20-%20And%20His%20Diving%20Seacopter.txt)